# oracle prompt before declare gives error

Tags: plsql

```
prompt ------------------------------------------------
prompt Executing...DDL/SCRIPT NAME.sql 
prompt ------------------------------------------------

SET SERVEROUTPUT ON;
SET VERIFY OFF;
  WHENEVER SQLERROR EXIT ;
  WHENEVER OSERROR EXIT ;

prompt DDL/JIRA-ID Checking columns UPDT_USERID, TIME_STAMP, LAST_ACTION for NULL values.
DECLARE
    v_error boolean := FALSE;
        v_exit EXCEPTION;
Begin
--- Some Code
END;
```

While running this code i am getting error at line

```
prompt DDL/JIRA-ID Checking columns UPDT_USERID, TIME_STAMP, LAST_ACTION for NULL values.
```

Error is as below.

```
    DDL/FND-18918 Checking columns UPDT_USERID, TIME_STAMP, LAST_ACTION for NULL values.
    prompt DDL/FND-18918 Checking columns HIST_USERID, HIST_TIME_STAMP, HIST_ACTION for NULL values.
           *

ORA-06550: 
PLS-00103: Encountered the symbol "DDL" when expecting one of the following: 
:= . ( @ % ; 
The symbol ":=" was substituted for "DDL" to continue. 
ORA-06550: 
PLS-00103: Encountered the symbol "CHECKING" when expecting one of the 
following: 
* & = - + ; < / > at in is mod remainder not rem 
<an exponent (**)> <> or != or ~= >= <= <> and or like like2 
like4 likec between || member submultiset
```

Can i know exact root cause of this. because i have long DDL script in which i have put prompt statement before every DECLARE block.

Answer (score 0):

```
I have tried your code only. Just modified a bit and its working fine.

        prompt ------------------------------------------------
prompt Executing...DDL/SCRIPT NAME.sql
prompt ------------------------------------------------

SET SERVEROUTPUT ON;
SET VERIFY OFF;
WHENEVER SQLERROR EXIT ;
WHENEVER OSERROR EXIT ;
prompt DDL/JIRA-ID Checking columns UPDT_USERID, TIME_STAMP, LAST_ACTION for NULL values.
DECLARE
  v_error BOOLEAN := FALSE;
  v_exit  EXCEPTION;
BEGIN
  --- Some Code
  NULL;
END;

------------------------------------------------
prompt Executing...DDL/SCRIPT NAME.sql
------------------------------------------------
DDL/JIRA-ID Checking columns UPDT_USERID, TIME_STAMP, LAST_ACTION for NULL values.
anonymous block completed
```

Answer (score 0):

Also please note the sqlplus command ending with - continues to next line..

And success/ not success also depends on your client.